# Boostrapping OpenMeetings

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, apache, styles, wicket, openmeetings

I am trying to boostrap OpenMeetings using this boostrap package https://github.com/l0rdn1kk0n/wicket-bootstrap. According to the tutorial of how to, I'll do it thus:

```
// best place to do this is in Application#init()
Bootstrap.install(this);

// if you want to customize bootstrap:
BootstrapSettings settings = new BootstrapSettings();
settings.setXXX(...);
Bootstrap.install(this, settings);
```

I am new to OpenMeetings, please can anyone kindly point me to where I am to put this snippet. As stated above it is suppose to be in Application#init(), but I don't know where the such a file could be in OpenMeetings.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the method you are looking for is here:

https://github.com/apache/openmeetings/blob/master/openmeetings-web/src/main/java/org/apache/openmeetings/web/app/Application.java#L172

BTW not sure "bootstraping" is possible. AFAIK bootstrap is in conflict with jquery-ui. Openmeetings heavily uses jquery-ui

Comment: If bootstrap isn't possible can custom CSS do the needful to improve and customize the UI?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you will have better success by using proper jQuery UI there that simulates Bootstrap: https://github.com/jquery-ui-bootstrap/jquery-ui-bootstrap